# Embedded Python (3.10) - Py_FinalizeEx hangs/deadlock on "threading._shutdown()"

Tags: python, c++, cpython, python-3.10

I am embedding Python in a C++ application, and I think I have some confusion with `PyGILState_Ensure/PyGILState_Release` which leads eventually to `Py_FinalizeEx` to hang in `threading._shutdown()` (called by `Py_FinalizeEx`) while `join()`-ing the threads.

During initialization I am calling:

```
Py_InitializeEx(0); // Skip installing signal handlers
auto gil = PyGILState_Ensure();
// ... running Python code
PyGILState_Release(gil);
```

Whenever a thread uses Python (can be multiple C-threads), I am using `pyscope` at the beginning of the function:

```
#define pyscope() \
    PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure(); \
    utils::scope_guard sggstate([&]() \
    { \
        PyGILState_Release(gstate); \
    });
```

When I want to free python I am calling (from a C-Thread, not necessarily one who initialized Python):

```
PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
int res = Py_FinalizeEx(); // <--- HANGS!!!
```

Debugging and reading the code revealed it hangs during joining of threads. I can reproduce the deadlock by running the following code with `PyRun_SimpleString` (running it right before Py_FinalizeEx):

```
import threading
    for t in threading.enumerate():
        print('get_ident: {} ; native: {}'.format(t.ident, t.native_id))
        if not threading.current_thread().ident == t.ident:
            t.join()
```

Last, I am not using PyEval_SaveThread/RestoreThread, maybe I have to, but I don't understand how to use them with GIL_Ensure/Release as I saw they are internally also taking and dropping the GIL.

Any ideas why the deadlock occurs and how to resolve this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because each time you acquire the gil you must release it, the main thread starts by acquiring the GIL once so you must reset the initial GIL count in the main thread by calling [PyEval_SaveThread](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.PyEval_SaveThread) in the main thread.

```cpp
Py_InitializeEx(0); // Skip installing signal handlers
PyThreadState* tstate = PyEval_SaveThread();

auto gil = PyGILState_Ensure();
// ... running Python code
PyGILState_Release(gil);
```

Minimal Reproducible Example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <processenv.h>
#include <thread>

namespace util {
    template<class F>
    class scope_guard {
        F func_;
        bool active_;
    public:
        scope_guard(F func) : func_(std::move(func)), active_(true) { }
        ~scope_guard() {
            if (active_) func_();
        }
    };

} // namespace util

#define pyscope() \
    PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure(); \
    util::scope_guard sggstate([&]() \
    { \
        PyGILState_Release(gstate); \
    })

void worker()
{
    PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
        "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
}
void worker2()
{
    pyscope();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
        "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    SetEnvironmentVariableA("PYTHONHOME", "C:\\Users\\blabla\\.conda\\envs\\py310");
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyThreadState* tstate = PyEval_SaveThread();

    auto thread2 = std::thread(worker2);
    thread2.join();

    auto GIL = PyGILState_Ensure();
    auto thread1 = std::thread(worker);
    PyGILState_Release(GIL);
    thread1.join();

    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tried it. Still hangs... do I need to restore the state at some point?

Comment: @TCS no you shouldn't restore the state ever again, you could even delete it with `PyThreadState_Clear` then `PyEval_SaveThread` then `PyThreadState_Delete`, i can duplicate the deadlock by not using `PyEval_SaveThread()` but no deadlock happens after using it, so maybe another thread has this same issue that's not the main thread ? do you create any threads from python itself that aren't daemon ?

Comment: @TCS could any of the C++ threads be stuck inside a function and unable to release the GIL ? the debugger could be off by a line, i have added an example for you to copy.