# Certain python functions hang from Python/C API

Tags: c++, c, cpython

I'm using the Python/C API to call Python functions from C++. My problem is that when I call a Python function that in turn imports `scipy.optimize.least_squares` then it hangs. Here are the details...

I'm calling my Python function `testfunc1(foo,bar=True)` in module `test_clib.py` as follows:

```
PyObject* pTestModuleName = PyUnicode_FromString( "test_clib" );
PyObject* pTestModule     = PyImport_Import( pTestModuleName );
PyObject* pFunction       = PyObject_GetAttrString( pTestModule, "testfunc1" );

const char* str = "foo";

PyObject* pArgList = Py_BuildValue( "(s)", str );

PyObject* pKeywords = PyDict_New();
PyDict_SetItemString( pKeywords, "bar", Py_True );

PyObject* pReturn = PyObject_Call( pFunction, pArgList, pKeywords );
```

When `testfunc1()` imports `scipy.optimize.least_squares` then it will hang. It doesn't even have to call least_squares. It will hang on this line:

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
```

But, when I boil it down to just a simple test program like I've shown here, it *works*. Where it fails is when the above snippet is part of my larger program.

So I realize this is not going to be something that someone else can directly try but maybe someone can spot something that I'm missing.

Maybe this will be helpful: when I run the test program in gdb it prints that about a dozen threads are started but my simple test program has no threads, so all of those must be from the C/Python API. When I try to run gdb on my larger program which makes the same Python calls, I don't see all those threads starting, it just hangs; when I interrupt it, it breaks here:

```
 ^C
 Thread 18 "acamd" received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.0x00007ffff73ca7e8 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
 (gdb) where
 #0  0x00007ffff73ca7e8 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib6/libpthread.so.0
 #1  0x00007ffff793bef5 in take_gil () from /lib64/libpython3.9.so.1.0    
 #2  0x00007ffff793c112 in PyEval_RestoreThread () from /lib64/libpython3.9.so.1.0
 #3  0x00007ffff7a5dd8c in PyGILState_Ensure () from /lib64/libpython3.9.so.1.0
 #4  0x00007fffb83bd6c5 in pybind11::detail::get_internals() () from /usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/_distance_pybind.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
 #5  0x00007fffb83ae22c in PyInit__distance_pybind () from /usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/_distance_pybind.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
 #6  0x00007ffff7a765bc in _imp_create_dynamic () from /lib64/libpython3.9.so.1.0
 #7  0x00007ffff7989ac8 in cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL () from /lib6/libpython3.9.so.1.0
 #8  0x00007ffff799a8eb in PyObject_Call () from /lib64/libpython3.9.so.1.0
 #9  0x00007ffff7a089d8 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () from /lib64/libpython3.9.so.1.0
 #10 0x00007ffff79f084e in _PyEval_EvalCode () from /lib64/libpython3.9.so.1.0
 #11 0x00007ffff 79f1e2b in _PyFunction_Vectorcall () from /lib64/libpython3.9.so.1.0
    :   :   :
```

which continues on for some 200 more lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the traceback (specifically `PyEval_RestoreThread`) indicates that the thread is stuck trying to reclaim the GIL (global interpreter lock).

things that can lead up to this point.

1. the GIL is held by another c++ thread and not releasing it
2. you have a mismatch in the number of times you have acquired and released the GIL in another thread

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed, that's a strong possibility. I haven't found the culprit yet but that gives me some direction. What I don't understand yet is that the working test snippet is all of the same Python-related code from the non-working version, so I'm not doing anything differently (I don't think!) -- in other words, if I have appropriately acquired/released the GIL above then I should be doing the same in the non-working code. What's different in the non-working code is that the snippet shown is called from a C++ thread, and in the working test code it's simply called from main().

Comment: printing PyGILState_Check() = 1 just before the call to PyObject_Call( pFunction, pArgList, pKeywords ) in the simple test stand-alone version, and =0 in the full version that hangs. -- so clearly I'm doing something different that I'm overlooking!

Comment: @astronomerdave maybe you just need to acquire the gil using [PyGILState_Ensure](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads), and release it after that ? (see the linked code), you could also check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75846775/embedded-python-3-10-py-finalizeex-hangs-deadlock-on-threading-shutdown/75847044#75847044) for threading python with c++ , lastly, you need to be checking for python exceptions.

Comment: that example was exactly it. Adding `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` / `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` to the top/bottom my my main(), and the referenced `pyscope()` call inside the thread which ultimately calls the function containing the py instance (the `Py_Initialize()` call) was indeed the solution.